# Can calibration break PSUs?

Tags: power-supply, calibration

I was tasked with rounding up all of my company's measurement devices (calipers, power supplies, scales, etc.) and arranging a visit from a calibration services company. The company came and calibrated them, put "passing" labels on them, and we've logged them to require re-calibration in 1-2 years.

However, two supplies (BK Precision, Ametek Sorensen) that have never had any issues before now have broken LCD displays and are unusable. One screen has a flashing "0" and one display is completely dead. Presumably they were working during the calibration procedure because they received "passing" labels. Could the calibration company have fried something if the procedure was done incorrectly, or is this a bizarre coincidence?

I know next to nothing about electronics, other than writing the Java code to interface with these supplies in test stations and having previously assessed the rise and fall times for setting timing on those test stations.

Comment: Certainly they could have damaged the units but proving it can be difficult. Did anyone from your company witness the calibration procedures? Did anyone check the units before the calibration company left the premises? Did you contact this company and ask them about these problems? Were you given any kind of calibration reports besides the stickers?

Comment: Did they do any adjustments, or only calibration?

Comment: What do the terms of your contract with the calibration company say about their quality of service, complaints, dispute mechanisms, and fixing problems?

Comment: What does the calibration report say they did? It smells like shipping damage to me though.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. The company has agreed to send someone over in a couple days to evaluate the devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ametek and Sorensen are the same company and the product design are similar. B&K are a different company. It would be surprising that there would be a common failure or error between those two.

Generally 'calibration' is verification of performance to specs; not adjustment to center or optimize the accuracy. In most cases therefore it is just verification of compliance to spec.

I know many of the Sorensen-type supplies are not 'closed-case' calibration - you have to open the case and adjust some potentiometer and/or measure some voltages. It is possible this was done incorrectly, but I expect this would result in bad calibration, not device failure. Also, the front-panel meters are quite separate from the regulators. Did you check that the output regulates correctly ? That might help narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a connector issue. One could speculate how that might happen, through normal procedures or through an error. It might be worth popping the covers and having a non-invasive look-see.

BK power supplies that I've seen are made by another company (which also sells under its own name) in Dongguan, China. They're very high volume and use proven, if pared to a minimum, designs.

In one BK design I'm familiar with the meters are 200mV and 200V with their own calibration pots, and each has an independent 5V supply isolated from everything else, but there would be not much point in calibrating the current meter out of circuit since it would not include the shunt tolerance. The voltage meter could be calibrated out of circuit.

Not familiar with the other firm.